# What options for statistical analysis with asp.net and ms-sql?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, statistics

I want to do some statistical analysis with an ms-sql database for an aps.net application.  What are the options as I don't see many built-in functions for my purpose? Thanks for any suggestions. Options that you actually use would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to supply us with more information; you're question is currently very vague. What do you want to analyze exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MathDotNet](http://www.mathdotnet.com), it can do pretty much anything you'd need.